# @Html.TextBoxFor not display a specific value

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, helper

I'm developing a website in ASP .Net with Razor.

For my forms i'm using Helpers (like `@Html.TextBoxFor`) and i'd like NOT to show a specific value. It's tricky to explain, so here's some code.

My model

```
public class SearchedInstruction
{
    private int _workCenterNumber= -1;
    public int WorkCenterNumber
    {
        get { return _idWorkCenter; }
        set { _idWorkCenter = value; }
    }
}
```

My view

```
@model InstructionSearchViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("InstructionSearch", "Search", FormMethod.Post, new { onsubmit = "submitSearchInstruction()" }))
{
    <div class="col-md-3">
        @Html.Label("Poste de charge")
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.WorkCenterNumber, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
}
```

So, of course, my `input` here has a value of `-1`, and, because i'm using this partial even in some other views, where the `WorkCenterNumber` is different than `-1`.

So, i'd like to display the `WorkCenterNumber` only when it's different than -1.

It may seem a bit stupid, but i hope there is someting in the helpers that'll allow me to do this.

Thanks !

**EDIT:** Additional random information added via a comment: "SearchedInstruction is a model from a custom framework of my company, so i'm not allowed to change this

Comment: Assume you mean `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.IdWorkCenter)` (not `WorkCenterNumber`). As always, use a view model and map you data model to the view model. If the value is -1, then don't set it (the view model property should be `int?`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use [magic numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29).

Here it appears you're using -1 to mean not-yet-specified-by-the-user, but maybe not, that's why you don't use numbers for meaning.

In this case, I'd change the `int` to a `nullable int` then the default value will be null and the textbox will be empty on first load.

**Edit**:  Additional random information added via a comment:  "SearchedInstruction is a model from a custom framework of my company, so i'm not allowed to change this".

In which case, add a new `ViewModel` for your view and map the values across (eg using AutoMapper or anything similar)

```
public class SearchedInstructionViewModel
{
    public int? IdWorkCenter { get;set; }
}
```

Change your view to use this viewmodel

```
@model SearchedInstructionViewModel
```

and populate in the controller

```
var model = db.SearchedInstruction.Load...  // however you load the *model*
var viewModel = new SearchedInstructionViewModel();
viewModel.IdWorkCenter = model.IdWorkCenter;
// etc, or use an automapper

return View(viewModel);
```

Comment: Same as below, i'm not allowed to change the model, but as @AmmarCSE said it, i'm gonna change it in the controller. I actually prefer your version. (I'd like to keep an int for the submit of the form). Thanks both of you guys !

Comment: Please add this requirement/restriction to the question!

Answer (score 2):

Simply change your get to the following which does the logic:

```
public class SearchedInstruction
{
    private int _idWorkCenter = -1;
    public string IdWorkCenter
    {
        get { return _idWorkCenter != -1 ? _idWorkCenter : string.Empty; }
        set { _idWorkCenter = value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Totally misunderstood his qeustion. Nice answer

Comment: Thought about this too, but the `SearchedInstruction` is a model from a custom framework of my company, so i'm not allowed to change this :/

Comment: @LeZohan68, change it in the controller before passing the model to the view